# Why my text form sqlite is show in single line?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting a list of texts from sqlite database and show them in a custom listview. The example of my text in database is like this:

Hello

Have are you?

But while I get this text from database and show it in my custom listview it show like this:
Hello Have are you?
My text show in single line! How to show it in multi line?
What the problem?!
Here is my example codes:

```
final SQLiteDatabase mydb = new MyDatabase2(EnglishActivity.this).getWritableDatabase();

Cursor cT=mydb.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE + " WHERE " 
                                           + TITLE + " LIKE ? " ,new String []{inputSearch.getText()+"%"});
array = new String[cT.getCount()];
                                        int i = 0;
while(cT.moveToNext()){
String uname = cT.getString(cT.getColumnIndex(TITLE));              array[i] = uname;
    i++;

                    }

    lv.setAdapter(  new EnCustomAdapter(EnglishActivity.this,array,tf));
```

My custom adapter:

```
public class EnCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {   


    Context context;
    String[] Maany;
    Typeface tff;


    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public EnCustomAdapter(Activity mainActivity, String[] maany, Typeface tf) {

        tff=tf;


        context=mainActivity;
        Maany=maany;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return result.length;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv1;

        Typeface t;


    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;       

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_english, null);

        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtFa);


        holder.tv.setText(Maany[position]);
        holder.tv.setTypeface(tff);
                return rowView;


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code of your  **`EnCustomAdapter`** ?

Comment: I added my custom adapter code to question

Comment: I think the issue is with the array **maany**, can you please debug the array maany in your adapter with breakPoints.

Comment: What the breakPoints? Can you help me?

Comment: I hope you are using Android Studio for development.If yes , you can go to your **EnCustomAdapter** class

Comment: In our constructor where you assign `Maany = maany;` on the left  side of editor , left click where the number line is displayed.This will add the breakpoint,now run your emulator or device by starting it in debug mode,follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo5PXWnKtQ4) to understand debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In your database save your data as:

```
Hello\nHave are you?
```

Include `\n` where ever you want a line to appear on a new line

Comment: I don't do this for thousands of the rows!